# Zero-crossing signal inconsistent timing

Tags: esp8266, dimming, zero-crossing, nodemcu

I have an ESP-07 with NodeMCU firmware connected to a dimming module with a zero-crossing pin.

The current frequency should be 50Hz, which means that the time between two zero crossing should be 10ms, ~10000 microseconds.

However the time between two interrupts is sometimes correct, but often is about ~450 microseconds.

What's the catch? I use tmr to measure time

Here is the code:

```
gpio.mode(2, gpio.INPUT)

gpio.mode(5, gpio.OUTPUT)

t = tmr.now();

counter = 0;

local function zc_callback(level, pulse)

    counter = counter + 1;
    counter = counter % 200;
    if(counter == 1) then
        print(tmr.now() - t);
    end

    t = tmr.now();

end

gpio.trig(2, "up", zc_callback)
```

Thank you, I try to figure this for some time, it affects my light bulbs which blink instead of dimming.

Comment: How long is your print going to take? Will everything wait until the print is finished?

Comment: I don't think it should matter because the time is measured before printing

Comment: But you're calling it every 10 ms if it's in the interrupt. Try taking it out.

Comment: I think you may also be forgetting to disable the interrupt on entry and re-enable on the way out. Won't that allow it to retrigger if the print routine isn't finished?

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope? Have you used it to look at the zero-cross signal to check for noise?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I got this, the mistake was the "up", "high" is what I need.

Comment: Thanks for closing this question. You can accept your own answer to mark it solved.